# geolocation not working on phone but working fine on emulator

Tags: android, geolocation

Belwo is the code which I am using to get location updates on my phone.
When I am running this on emulator and manually feeding latitude and longitude from emulator control its working fine but when i am trying to run this app on my phone its not showing any co-ordinates.
Please help..

manifest file has required permissions -

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have checked and GPS is switched on my phone

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,ll);   
}
    class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(location!=null)
            {
                double lo = location.getLongitude();
                double la = location.getLatitude();                 
                lati.setText(Double.toString(la));
                longi.setText(Double.toString(lo));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try with Network provider.GPS provider takes time to obtain lock

Comment: phone is connected to internet.if connected to internet which type like 2g,3g (or) wifi

Comment: wifi and when i leave from home it runs on 2g

Comment: turn on gps on your mobile and use 3g (or) wifi is better!

Comment: gps is already on..and i trid up with wifi

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the GPS is turned on in your device. GPS provider fails to work inside a building. Inside a building you need to use the WiFi provider.

Comment: I tried in open area..it was working on 2g and didnt captured any co-ordinates from GPS